# T is multliplication by a primitive element

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Consider $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb F_{p}$. Now let $T$ be a non-zero  $\Bbb F_{p}$-linear map from $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ to $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. Now if $0$ and $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ are the only $T$-invariant subspace of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ then we have to prove that $T=aI$ (i.e multiplication by $a$) where $\Bbb F_{p^n}=\Bbb F_{p}(a)$ (i.e  $a$ is a primitive element of $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ over $\Bbb F_{p}$).

What I have tried:

Clearly $T$ is an isomorphism. So $T$ has finite order as an element in the invertible matrix group over $\Bbb F_{p}$, say $d$. Then for every non-zero element $v$, $v+T(v)+T^2(v)+\dots+T^{d-1}(v)=0$.

But I can't proceed further. I need some help.

Comment: In the context of finite fields *a primitive element* = *a generator of the multiplicative group*. While this is standard it is a bit unfortunate given that elsewhere in the theory of field extensions it means that it generates the field extension (which is what you obviously meant).

Comment: The problem here is that once you forget the original field structure on $\Bbb{F}_p^n$ (viewing it only as a vector space), the mapping $T$ may come from a *different* field structure. See my answer for details/examples. Probably whoever asked you this question didn't mean that you would get back the original field structure, but that's the impression the way you phrased the questions gives to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken literally, the claim is FALSE as stated. Consider the case $p=3$, $n=2$. We construct the field $\Bbb{F}_9$ as $\Bbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Let $\alpha$ denote a root of $x^2+1$ in $\Bbb{F}_9$. Let's use the basis $1,\beta=1+\alpha$, and define the mapping $T$ by $T(1)=1+\alpha$, $T(1+\alpha)=-1$, i.e. $T$ is the linear transformation with the matrix
$$
M(T)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right).
$$
There are no non-trivial $T$-invariant subspaces for such a subspace would be 1-dimensional over $\Bbb{F}_3$ and thus an eigenspace of $T$ belonging to eigenvalue $\in\Bbb{F}_3$. But the eigenvalues of $T$ are fourth roots  of unity. Also, $T$ is not multiplication by a generating element $a$ of $\Bbb{F}_9$. As $T(1)=1+\alpha$ the only possibility would be $a=1+\alpha$. But $T(1+\alpha)=-1\neq(1+\alpha)^2=2\alpha$.

The problem with the above "literal" interpretation of the question is that you began by declaring the structure of a field to $\Bbb{F}_p^n$. A true statement would be as follows.

**Claim.** Let $T:\Bbb{F}_p^n\to\Bbb{F}_p^n$ be a linear mapping that has no non-trivial invariant subspaces. Then the ring $R=\Bbb{F}_p[T]$ gotten by adjoining the powers of $T$ to the field of scalar matrices is a field of $p^n$ elements, IOW $R\cong \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$.

**Proof.** Consider the minimal polynomial $p(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ of $T$. If it is of degree less than $n$, then we easily get a non-trivial $T$-invariant subspace. The same holds if $p(x)$ is not irreducible (the details depend a little on whether $p(x)$ has a factor with multiplicity $>1$ or whether it's separable). This implies that the subring $R$ of $M_n(\Bbb{F}_p)$ generated by $T$ and the scalar matrices is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\cong\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. Q.E.D.

**The moral.** We can embed the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ into $M_n(\Bbb{F}_p)$ in many somewhat unrelated ways. I say "somewhat unrelated", because if $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are two such embeddings, then by the [Skolem-Noether Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) they differ from each other by conjugation. More precisely, there exists an invertible matrix $A\in GL_n(\Bbb{F}_p)$ such that
$$
\phi_2(x)=A\phi_1(x)A^{-1}
$$
for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$.

Comment: For example the mapping $T$ becomes a fourth root of unity of a field of niine elements, but it is not the same field we started with. When viewed as subspaces of 2x2 matrices, the two fields are different.

Comment: I see how to get a nontrivial $T$-invariant subspace when $p\left(x\right)$ is not irreducible (indeed, if $p\left(x\right) = q\left(x\right) r\left(x\right)$, then $\operatorname{Ker}\left(q\left(T\right)\right)$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, and easily seen to be neither trivial nor full when $q\left(x\right)$ is a proper nontrivial factor). But how do we get such a subspace if $p\left(x\right)$ has degree less than $n$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see -- one should then take $\mathbb{F}_p\left[T\right] \cdot u$ for some $u \in \mathbb{F}_p^n \setminus \operatorname{Ker} T$. This is not an argument I'd leave to the reader, though.